# How to fix flickering screen

Tags: windows, laptop, display

I have `Dell 15.6-Inch Gaming Laptop (6th Gen Intel Quad-Core i5-6300HQ Processor up to 3.2GHz, 8GB DDR3, 256GB SSD, Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M, Windows 10)`. Its two years old now, and the screen flickers all the time.

This started long time ago and I can't identify the source of the problem. Once I had an adapter for the wire that connects to the outlet, and in time it was damaged a little. I felt lazy about changing it, so I left it and I didn't replace it.

It often produced electrical sounds, and I didn't feel good about it. I then replaced it but that happened after the monitor started flickering.

Now the question is, could it be the reason of this problem? Are there other possibilities I should think of?

Comment: have you see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZCBrh3Yzrk ?

Comment: @derloopkat I am afraid that didn't help.

Comment: maybe its a software/driver problem - you can include a screenshot of your display/graphics properties in the above question. and mention the steps you have already taken or tried, so that other users can offer alternatives

Comment: Does the screen flicker when you are booting and still in the BIOS? (Press F2 to enter the BIOS during boot)

Comment: @harrymc Actually, the computer boots up fast, so I don't get to notice flickering during boot time, but I'll try to enter BIOS and see if the screen flickers there.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can isolate the problem by plugging in an external monitor. If the external monitor is also flickering then you know the problem is OS\Driver\Software based. If only the internal monitor is flickering then move to step 2
2. Open the laptop and find the ribbon that connects the display to the motherboard. Unplug, check for evidence of burning using both sight and smell. Plug back in and re-assemble. If you don't find clear evidence of burning or damage to the ribbon or connectors then sometimes unplugging and plugging back in can fix faulty connections. If the problem still persists after reassembly move to step 3
3. Disassemble the top half and inspect the connection of the ribbon to the internal panel. Check around the connection there for signs of damage.

If you don't see or smell any damage in your physical inspection the problem could be a little deeper. Begin replacing parts: Panel, Ribbon, Motherboard. It might be easier to hit it with a baseball bat and move on with your life.